# Julia set code creates a circle instead of a fractal

Tags: python, fractals, mandelbrot

I have this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import colorsys

xmin, xmax = -2.0, 2.0
ymin, ymax = -2.0, 2.0

depth = 12

imgx, imgy = 512, 512

maxIter = 256

image = Image.new("RGB", (imgx, imgy))

for y in range(imgy):
    cy = y * (ymax - ymin)/(imgy - 1) + ymin
    for x in range(imgx):
        cx = x * (xmax - xmin)/(imgx - 1) + xmin
        c = complex(cx, cy)
        z = 0
        for i in range(maxIter):
            if abs(z) > 2.0:
                break
            z = c + complex(0.25, 0.1)
        r = i
        g = int((i*50)%256)
        b = int(255 - i)
        image.putpixel((x, y), (r, g, b))
```

It creates an image of a circle (image below), and I can't understand why. I think it might have something to do with the for loops and the if statements, but I can't figure out what the problem would be. If it's not that, what is it?

Side note: this code is adapted from a Mandelbrot set code I wrote. The only difference is that instead of `z = c + complex(0.25, 0.1),` I have `z = z**2 + c.`

[Julia Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWFug.png)

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
What values does this code produce for display?  Please supply an illustrative tracing output.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code fails for undefined symbols -- probably a missing `import`.

Comment: @Prune Sorry, forgot to upload image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

`z = c + complex(0.25, 0.1)`

always yields the same value (current point + a constant) in each iteration, so your code just draws a circle. Change that line to

`z = z**2 + complex(0.25, 0.1)`

and initialize `z` based on the current point (like `c` is in your current code).